# How to close if you don't have enough rep

Tags: discussion

I flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28328205/in-angularjs-what-is-the-cleanest-way-to-declare-a-factory-service) question as "other" with the comment that it was subjective.  The flag was declined with the reason *"declined - Use the canonical close reasons."*.

I don't know what rep is required to close, but I don't see any option to close; I figured the best way would be to flag for moderator attention.

Comment: flag for "primarily opinion based" :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just flag it for closure with a standard close flag.

The "Other" option isn't available to flaggers, so just pick the closest close reason you can.

Custom flags should **not** be used for simple question closure.

Comment: I see... I don't think any of my available flags are close to subjective -- they all sound pretty harsh (spam, offensive, duplicate).  But, noted.  I'll find a way to make it work in the future, thanks

Comment: @Tom You should hit, in this case, "It should be closed for another reason..." which will bring up a sub menu with more options, one of which is "Primarily Opinion Based". In general, if there is a "..." at the end of an option in the menus here, it leads to a sub menu.