# Shouldn't homework questions with no work done be closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, declined-flags

Consider this question: ["Submatrix quantizer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34482553/submatrix-quantizer)

This question is an [off-topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) because it falls under this category:

> Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Shouldn't it be closed? I flagged it and it got declined; now I'm banned from flagging.

Comment: The banning process for many things is a little opaque and often applied without any warning.

Comment: see also: [Is using Stack Overflow for gimme codez questions encouraged?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288133/is-using-stack-overflow-for-gimme-codez-questions-encouraged)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error was that you used the **incorrect flag**

"in need of moderator intervention", this should be used only if something "fishy" is going on (and homework question is not fishy).... the moderators are few so the rest of the community tries to handle "standard business" stuff.

I flagged it like this:

> Should be closed
>
> off-topic because...
>
> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the
> shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.
> Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other
> readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable
> example.

**EDIT:** As @psubsee2003 pointed out in comment this is probably not the perfect close reason for this question, he suggest to use "unclear" or "too broad" providing the following very useful links.

[Is "too broad" a valid reason to close a question that doesn't show any research effort?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283177/is-too-broad-a-valid-reason-to-close-a-question-that-doesnt-show-any-research/283185#283185)

[Improving "demonstrate a minimal understanding" close reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211080/improving-demonstrate-a-minimal-understanding-close-reason/215546#215546)

After reading the answers and specially comments ..

> @Shog9 this is a question which I would have, without a doubt,
> previously VTCd as "demonstrate a minimal understanding of the
> problem." It's a lousy, help-vampirish request for icanhazcodez but I
> really disagree that "too broad" is a sensible close reason.
>
> I'm not actually recommending the use of "Too Broad" for questions like these, @Matt. Quite the opposite. I've tweaked the
> emphasis in this post. – Shog9♦ Jan 10 '14 at 23:00
>
> @Shog9 okay, so we closed that question as "unclear what you're
> asking." But the question – the task the OP is trying to accomplish –
> is perfectly clear! – Matt Ball Jan 10 '14 at 23:04
>
> What's he asking for, @Matt? Even after reading that question twice, I don't even know which language he wants a solution in, much
> less which "last" element he's referring to. There's some
> clarification in the comments, and someone took a guess at an answer,
> but... No, this is not a clear question. – Shog9♦

So the correct closing flag for this question is:

**unclear what you're asking**

> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to
> highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard
> to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help
> clarifying this question.

But I did not get banned for *off-topic*.....

Comment: Your close flag reason for these questions is (usually) incorrect as the user does not usually provide any code and is not looking for debugging help.  While I don't think it will happen again with this close reason, we have had close reasons removed in the past because of mass misuse.  So please do not use close reasons incorrectly.  For questions of this nature, most are usually either "unclear" or "too broad", so I suggest you use those.

Comment: @psubsee2003, thanks which of the two do you prefer, to unclear (its seems pretty clear), to broad (hmm, seems that you can answer in a fairly short way...), please help me out which is the best choice..

Comment: It's not a one-size-fits-all approach.  Every post should be evaluated on its own merits.  Take a look at my answer to [Is “too broad” a valid reason to close a question that doesn't show any research effort?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283177/is-too-broad-a-valid-reason-to-close-a-question-that-doesnt-show-any-research/283185#283185) and there are other similar questions.

Comment: but to address the concept in general, here's the best explanation for why questions of this type are often unclear or too broad: [Improving “demonstrate a minimal understanding” close reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211080/improving-demonstrate-a-minimal-understanding-close-reason/215546#215546), but there are also several good answers on that post, so take a look at them all.

Comment: @psubsee2003, 1000 Thanks, there is always things to learn, i have updated my answer.

Comment: @psubsee2003 this classic looks also worth mentioning, isn't it: ["ME: Click the right mouse button.
NOOB: What's a mouse?"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261859/839601)

Answer (score 3):

Closed, yes...that's what **Close Votes** are for.

Flagging...No. It would not be appropriate here to flag as it *not* one of:

- **spam**
- **rude or abusive**
- **should be closed**...This question is completely unclear, etc.
- **a duplicate...**
- **in need of moderator intervention**

### *unless* you do not have sufficient reputation to cast a close vote

If, as it appears, you did not have sufficient reputation to cast a close vote then flagging..as you say, is your only option.

**However**, marking for moderator attention is incorrect...you just have to pick the closest option available to you..per this [**Meta Q&A**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285351/how-to-close-if-you-dont-have-enough-rep?lq=1)

> Just flag it for closure with a standard close flag.
>
> The "Other" option isn't available to flaggers, so just pick the closest close reason you can.
>
> Custom flags should not be used for simple question closure.

Comment: The OP does not have enough reputation to vote to close, so they have to flag, which has the same effect.

Comment: yeah. can't vote. flagged as **in need of moderator intervention** (I think)

Comment: Ah...updated answer....wrong flag raised.

Comment: That said, you wouldn't be flag deprived due to a single bad flag...you should look into that.

Comment: @Paulie_D Cool. Thanks. I have 2 more edits that got declined (very bad quality questions) and that got me banned. Too bad that SO won't show you the details of each flag you did.

Comment: @PetterFriberg - I think the OP just forgot to remove *should be closed...* from that list when updating their answer.